# Does `Promise.all` suffer from the limit of concurrent connections imposed by the browser?

Tags: javascript, http, http2

Assume an api server is using HTTP/1.1 and the browser has a limit of 6 concurrent TCP connections per domain.
Does that mean if I do 7 api calls at once with `Promise.all` then the last `api` will have to wait for the first `api`'s request to come back over the network?

```js
Promise.all([api(), api(), api(), api(), api(), api(), api()]) // 7 api calls
```

Also does HTTP/2 solve this problem with multiplexing where all the these API calls will be on the same connection so they don't need to wait for anything?

Comment: This is an example of the kind of thing that you really can't "know" for sure. The behavior of the API is not really something that's specified exactly.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with promises. The `api()` calls do become concurrent not because you're using `Promise.all`, but because you fire them off all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean if I do 7 api calls at once with Promise.all then the last api will have to wait for the first api's request to come back over the network?

Yes, it does.

Your `Promise.all([api(), api(), ...])` statement will immediately run all `api()` function calls.  That will cause the first 6 requests to get sent and the 7th will be queued until one of the first 6 finishes in which case the browser will the send the 7th.

This behavior doesn't actually have anything to do with `Promise.all()`.  The same behavior would occur if you just did this:

```
const promises = [api(), api(), api(), api(), api(), api(), api()];
```

Even with just that statement, the 7th http request wouldn't get sent to the host until one of the first 6 had completed.  It's entirely because of the browser's connection limits to the same host.

FYI, the `Promise.all()` will still work and all the api requests will still work, it will just have to wait a bit longer for all requests to complete than if you weren't hitting the connection limits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but this isn't a limitation particular to `Promise.all`. In general, an expression like

```
anotherFn([fn(), fn(), fn()])
```

is equivalent to doing

```
const r1 = fn();
const r2 = fn();
const r3 = fn();
anotherFn([r1, r2, r3]);
```

Everything inside the argument list gets evaluated before the result is passed. If the process of evaluating everything makes a bunch of API calls, the other function - `Promise.all` or `anotherFn` cannot possibly do anything about that, because those occur before the function runs.

> then the last api will have to wait for the first api's request to come back over the network?

If we can assume that the restrictions are as you've said - the browser is limited to 6 connections to the API at once - then yes.

Yes, HTTP/2 is of great help in these sorts of situations, because they need only one connection per domain, and can send multiple requests over that connection, without running into the browser connection limit.